# Cannot find symbol variable edit_message

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I am working through the Android Studio Developer Guide right now and trying to complete their example app.  I have followed everything step by step but I am having a confusing problem with the IDE not recognizing a certain variable `edit_message`.  I looked up other people who had this error and their problem was not declaring the string in strings.xml but I have made sure to do that.  Here is my main class where the error is occurring:

```
package com.example.darks.videodeck;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.darks.videodeck";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the strings.xml file just so you can see that the `edit_message` declared in that file and the `edit_message` not being recognized are the same:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">VideoDeck</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>

</resources>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your Xml file also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.edit_message` is a **layout** `id`, so you have to set it on an `EditText` in your `activity_my.xml` layout. Like this :

### activity_my.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width=...
    android:layout_height=...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't be confuse with `id` resource and `string` resource. You have defined `edit_message` as string resource but accessing it through `id` resource. If your `activity_my` contains `edit_message` as an EditText then it won't give error.

Answer (score 1):

findViewById(int) used to retrieve the widgets in UI to interact with programmatically.

In your code `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`
 will look for a EditText on your main layout "activity_my.xml" identified by the id.